# Create alert based on accounts table with a last_updated UTC datetime field

Tags: sql-server, alerts

I have database that has a phone app as a front end.  There is an webaccounts table that stores the token of the user and login info like last_login_date.

We had an incident yesterday where no one can access the site.  When I check this table there was only 1 user that was able to login for the past 3 days.  It was the app developers login token = [1234].  I was wondering if you could give me ideas of how to create  a query that will monitor this table if token 1234 is the only accessing this table over a period of time.  Let's say 15 minutes.

These are the columns for the webaccounts table:

```
[last_login_at][createdAt]
[updatedAt]
[refmd_id]
[api_token]
```

The api_token that is used by the app is token = 1234  (this is just an example - not an actual token)

If you have a better idea of the best way to monitor this table, please let me know.  We're trying to make sure we know when there is a connection issue and users are not able to access the database.

Comment: The question is. Who will monitor that your alert is working?

Comment: What have you tried so far? I'm seeing a list of columns but no attempt at a query that satisfies your requirements.

Comment: I haven't created any scripts yet as I wasn't sure what direction to take or if what I am suggesting would even work.  The way I was thinking this might work is to create a stored procedure to run in  a job that would check to see if there is more than "developer users" based off last_login_at.  If it detects no users besides this one in the past 15 minutes; I would have to sendmail to the DBA alerts email group.  I just not quite sure how to get started which is why I'm reaching out.    The app user is always connected which is why I have to somehow check another way.